# El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: dataSet ASP.NET Y SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, .net

Cuando quiero ver los datos del GridView me sale este error:

> El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: dataSet.

Él agrega a la base de datos, pero al momento de consultar los valores de un producto por ID, me sale ese error.

Aquí el código:

```
public DataSet stConsultarProductos(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet dsConsulta = null;

                sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(stConexion);
                sqlConnection.Open();


                sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("ConsultarProductos", sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idProducto", id));



                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsConsulta);

                return dsConsulta;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            finally { sqlConnection.Close(); }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo creo entender, según la línea:
*sqlDataAdapter.Fill(**dsConsulta**);*
que con el parámetro *dataSet* se refiere al parámetro del método Fill de la clase SqlDataAdapter, de la que está instanciado el objeto sqlDataAdapter en su función stConsultarProductos(int Id). Dicho parámetro es (si no entiendo mal) de "tipo" DataSet. Y por lo que veo, en dicho método *Fill*, NO SE admite un valor NULO en susodicho parámetro.
Puesto que, en la primera línea del bloque try {...}, veo que has inicializado la variable (el objeto...) *dsConsulta* como **null**, y posteriormente, no he visto ninguna línea en la que ajustes dicha variable a un valor diferente a **null** hasta susodicha línea en la que llamas al método Fill de sqlDataAdapter, veo lógico que te salga el error de "valor nulo" en el parámetro dataSet del método Fill.

En cuanto a una posible solución, no sé (voy a ser sincero, yo no estoy muy puesto en ASP, soy más de PHP y MySQL...), pero probaría a sustituír la línea donde pones
*DataSet dsConsulta = null;*
por
*DataSet dsConsulta = new DataSet(...);*
Bueno... si es que eso puede ponerse así en .ASP, que como decía...
Bueno,
Saludos

Comment: Su apreciacion es correcta, se debe inicializar el dataset con new DataSet();

Comment: Gracias, si es como dicen pero también hay que sacar el DataSet fuera del try, muchas gracias amigos...